# Is there a way to approve an =ImportRange(url,range) using a google scripts function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I am creating a Google Sheets document to be distributed to teachers. The document uses the school calendar and bell schedules to make "assignment sheets" (or syllabus) because classes do not meet every day or at the same time. I am trying to make it easier to make changes to the schedule by using `=importRange(url,range)`. This way, if I change something on my master schedule, it is automatically updated in all users sheets.

I am attempting to make a script that will automatically say "yes" to the "Allow Access" prompt.
Is that possible? I am guessing no, since they ask the question, but I am hoping there is a script function for this.

Answer (score 1):

While working a lot with `Importrange`, I've never came across a solution that will enable the access automatically with a code.

**Workaround**:

- Your Master copy is a spreadsheet shared with `Anyone with the link`
  as `Viewer`
- The tab containing the data in your Master copy has a Whole Sheet Protection and it's hidden (Click right on tab: *Protect Sheet*, and Click right again: *Hide Sheet*)
- Then in the spreadsheets where you use `Importrange`, I would insert
  the formula in a hidden row/column that it is protected itself as well

**Outcome**:

By doing so, all your spreadsheets are connected without the need of enabling the access to your Master copy. Your colleagues cannot really retrieve the link of your master copy by looking at the Importrange formula since it's within a hidden row/column

**Hacking possibility**:

I'm explaining this point relatively to how important your data are, otherwise it's not a big issue.

In case someone is very persistent to access your Master copy, they could download the spreadsheet shared with them (spreadsheet where you have `Importrange`) as an excel file. Then when accessing the excel file, **IF** they understand that the formula is within a hidden row/column, they will find the `URL` that you have used, then they would try to access your document (copy/paste URL), which they can because it's shared with everyone. But, they will find nothing except a tab with no data at all, because your tab containing the data is protected and hidden, they will never be able to open it as well. And because it is shared with everyone as `Viewer`, they cannot either download your Master copy as an excel file !!

One possibility remains though: they open your Master copy where they see nothing, but they need to use a software to record their screen for hours and hours, and watch if you came or not to open the hidden tab containing the data.

Comment: Possible easy way to get the master url is by using page>view-source. Another way is to monitor outgoing network connections. In any case, from a security standpoint, the solution is weak.